# nullPointerException on FXML object while manually adding controllers

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, fxml

I'm making a application where PuzzleBlocks are being constructed in a grid of 5x5 rectangles. I've moved away from declaring fx:controller in the .fxml file and instead did this in main:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader baseViewLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Views/BaseView.fxml"));
        baseViewLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Views/BaseView.fxml"));
        baseViewLoader.setController(new DockViewController());
        Parent root = baseViewLoader.load();

        FXMLLoader dockLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Views/DockView.fxml"));
        dockLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Views/DockView.fxml"));
        dockLoader.setController(new DockViewController());
        Parent dockView = dockLoader.load();

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Tiles 2059275");

        Scene gameScene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(gameScene);

        primaryStage.show();

        new GameController();
    }
```

Now previously when it was done via having the Controller declared via the .fxml file this piece of code in the Initialize of my DockViewController would work properly:

```
@FXML
    StackPane dockStackPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                tile1 = createSquare(Color.GREY);
                tile2 = createSquare(Color.GREY);
                tile3 = createSquare(Color.GREY);

                tile1.setTranslateX(32 * (i) - 176);
                tile1.setTranslateY(32 * (j) - 48);

                tile2.setTranslateX(32 * (i) - 16);
                tile2.setTranslateY(32 * (j) - 48);

                tile3.setTranslateX(32 * (i) + 144);
                tile3.setTranslateY(32 * (j) - 48);

                dockStackPane.getChildren().add(tile1);
                dockStackPane.getChildren().add(tile2);
                dockStackPane.getChildren().add(tile3);

                puzzleBlock1.add(tile1);
                puzzleBlock2.add(tile2);
                puzzleBlock3.add(tile3);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Ini test");
    }
```

The error occurs at `dockStackPane.getChildren().add(tile1);` because dockStackPane is null. If I remove manually adding the controllers in my Main and return to adding the controllers with fx:controller in the FXML file it works properly. But then I do not have a reference to my controller.

DockView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="128.0" prefWidth="384.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <StackPane fx:id="dockStackPane" prefHeight="128.0" prefWidth="384.0" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

And the DockView is included in the BaseView

Comment: @Fabian ```@FXML StackPane dockStackPane;``` returns null when I try to use it now I've manually assigned the Controller. If I instead add the controller via fx:controller in the view then it does work. But then I don't have a reference to my DockViewController

Comment: Why are you using the same controller class for both controllers? Do both FXML files have a `dockStackPane`? Is the exception occurring during `baseViewLoader.load()` or `dockLoader.load()`?

Comment: @James_D During dockLoader.load() because that's when it is trying to Initialize. Once again when I had fx:controller set on the pane element to DockViewController in DockView.fxml this code was working properly.

Comment: *"And the DockView is included in the BaseView"*. Can you elaborate? Do you use `<fx:include>`? Is the `<StackPane>` in `BaseView.fxml` too? `FXMLLoader` won't inject fields from included fxmls to the controller of the including fxml.

Comment: I use fx:incldue the StackPane is not in BaseView.fxml too

Comment: It will call `initialize()` whenever it loads. If you don't have a `dockStackPane` in `BaseView.fxml`, then when `initialize()` is called on `baseViewLoader` you will get a null pointer exception. But why are you explicitly loading `DockView.fxml` if it is already included via a `<fx:include>`?

Comment: @James_D Because if I set the controller via fx:controller I wouldn't have a reference to my Controller, so in that piece of code I am setting the controller for that view and then passing along the instance of the controller so I can use it in my GameController. Or am I going wrong here?

Comment: @StrahBehry You can get the controller instance after loading the fxml using `FXMLLoader.getController()`. Controllers of included fxmls can be injected to the controller of the including fxml, if you specify a `fx:id` for the `<fx:include>` tag and add a field accessible to the FXMLLoader to the controller of the including fxml. The name of this field should be tha concatenation of the `fx:id` value and `Controller`, e.g. `fooController` for `fx:id="foo"`.

Comment: Use the [Nested Controllers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) approach to inject the controller for the included FXML into the controller for the including FXML, as fabian describes. (Each FXML file needs a different controller class.) With your approach, apart from the NPE, you are loading a second copy of `DockView.fxml` and getting the controller for the copy. You want the controller for the UI that is actually included. So you would have a reference to the wrong controller anyway.

Comment: @James_D managed to get it working, really appreciate your help, answered my own question, is this proper what I've done now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments to my question I was able to work it out the solution is to add a fx:id to the include in my BaseView.fxml:

```
 <fx:include fx:id="includedDockView" source="DockView.fxml" />
```

Make sure the include element then has a fx:controller set as so:

```
<Pane fx:id="dockPane" fx:controller="tiles.Controllers.DockViewController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="128.0" prefWidth="384.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

Then in the BaseViewController you can do:

```
@FXML
    private DockViewController includedDockViewController;

    public DockViewController getDockViewController() {
        return includedDockViewController;
    }
```

And in the main you can pass the BaseView as such:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader baseViewLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Views/BaseView.fxml"));
    baseViewLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Views/BaseView.fxml"));
    baseViewLoader.setController(new BaseViewController());
    Parent root = baseViewLoader.load();

    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Tiles 2059275");

    Scene gameScene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(gameScene);

    primaryStage.show();

    new GameController(baseViewLoader);
}
```

Comment: The last line of that code doesn't do anything: other than that this looks like the correct approach.